# Passing data through Java FX Controller to other View

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxmlloader

I guess it's a simple question but it was a long day at work and I cant figure the right way out right now.

I have 3 FXML files.

- `Menge.fxml`
- `Start.fxml`
- `Suche.fxml`

I'm starting from Main.java as usual

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Start.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Inside the `MainController` I've got the following `ActionListener`

```
@FXML
void actionListenerMenge(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menge.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I'm opening the `Suche.fxml` via the FXMLLoader. 
Now there is a `button` inside my Suche-View which opens another scene for where the user should search the specific data record.

```
@FXML
void actionListenerSuche(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Suche.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`SucheController` where I'm loading the `MengeController` again via FXMLLoader

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menge.fxml"));
try {
    Parent root = loader.load();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
MengeController controller = (MengeController)loader.getController();
```

I want to edit the value inside a `TextField` @ the `MengeController` to update the View from my `Menge.fxml`. But if I do

`controller.setTextFieldValue("abc")` it's not updating. I know it must be because I've loaded the `MengeController` twice and so there are two instances. But I don't figure out how to load it only once or inject it to update my `TextField` inside `MengeController`.

Comment: I think you mean "So I'm opening the `Menge.fxml` via the FXMLLoader. Now there is a button inside my Menge-view...". Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: The Flow is Start -> Open the `Menge.fxml` (which contains a tableview) via ButtonClick -> Open the `Suche.fxml` (which containts search parameters for data records) via ButtonClick (the button is located in `Menge.fxml`).

Comment: Can you [edit] the question then? That's not what it says...

Comment: will edit it later that day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Observe a property in the `SucheController`:**

Define a property in the `SucheController`. Instead of trying to get a reference back to the `MengeController`, just set the property:

```
public class SucheController {

    private final ObjectProperty<Foo> foo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Foo> fooProperty() {
        return foo() ;
    }

    public final Foo getFoo() {
        return fooProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        fooProperty().set(foo);
    }

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void someHandlerMethod() {

        // FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menge.fxml"));
        // try {
        //     Parent root = loader.load();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        //     e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // MengeController controller = (MengeController)loader.getController();

        setFoo(...);
    }
}
```

Obviously replace `Foo` with a type that represents whatever data the user is providing here, and name the property and methods accordingly...

Now when you load Suche.fxml, just get a reference to the controller and observe the property. Then you can just update the text field directly in `MengeController` itself:

```
@FXML
void actionListenerSuche(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Suche.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

        SucheController sucheController = loader.getController();
        sucheController.fooProperty().addListener((obs, oldFoo, newFoo) -> {
            someTextField.setText(newFoo.getSomeValue());
            // ...
        });

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2: Pass a reference to the `MengeController` directly to the `SucheController`:**

Another option, which I don't like as much as it involves more coupling between the controllers, is simply to pass a reference to the `MengeController` to the `SucheController`:

```
public class SucheController {

    private MengeController mengeController ;

    public void setMengeController(MengeController mengeController) {
        this.mengeController = mengeController ;
    }

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void someHandlerMethod() {

        mengeController.setTextFieldValue("abc");

    }
}
```

and then the code in your `MengeController` that loads Suche.fxml looks like

```
@FXML
void actionListenerSuche(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Suche.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

        SucheController sucheController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        sucheController.setMengeController(this);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```